# Discord bot that welcomes users (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Please')

@bot.command()
async def _say(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   await client.get_channel(819281283803906071).send(f"{member.name} has joined")


bot.run('Token')
```

Trying to make a bot that will @ and welcome users when they join with a message.
This is the code but nothing happens on member join, I don't even get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several errors in the code here.

**First)** You use `bot`, but query the channel with `client.get_channel`, that does not make any sense.

**Second)** You have to enable the intents in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.

**Your whole event:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Please', intents=intents) # Add the intents to your code

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   channel = bot.get_channel(819281283803906071)
   await channel.send(f"{member.name} has joined!")
```